# Shared folder crashing Ubuntu VM (Mac OS Host)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have managed to set up an ubuntu server VM (using Oracle VirtualBox) which will eventually be part of a small Hadoop practice cluster.  I have followed along with various tutorials online and I'm now trying to set up a shared folder between the guest and host OS.  I have installed the latest version of Guest Additions using the built in package manager.

The problem is that once I mount the shared folder in the guest OS, if I try to ls the contents of that folder, the OS hangs and I am forced to restart the VM.  If I ls the folder prior to mounting the shared folder no errors occur.

However, if I try to `touch /media/sf_VMshare/testfile`, the file appears in the corresponding host OS directory as if everything is working correctly.

I am at the limit of what I know to do to troubleshoot this on my own.  If anyone had any suggestions as to what to try next I would be in your debt.

Thanks!

FYI:
mount cmd: `sudo mount -t vboxsf VMShare /media/sf_VMShare` where VMShare is defined in the VirtualBox manager.

Comment: I just wanted to update this post to say that in spite of the aforementioed bug I am able to read and write files to and from the shared folder to the host OS and vice-versa.  However, the system still hangs if I run any command that indexes the folder, including attempting to tab-complete file names from the command line.  So the folder WAI but any action that lists the contents crashes the shell.  What would cause such a strange bug?

Comment: If I try to copy a file using `cp /media/sf_VMShare/testfile ~/`, I can use ctrl-C to break out of the hang.  However, `ls /media/sf_VMShare` still won't respond to interrupts.